# Maintain scroll position in two columns on reload

Tags: javascript, html, css

Desperately reaching out here now!

My webpage contains three columns with three different divs: "primary", "main" and "secondary".

I would like to maintain the scrollpositions of **all** divs on reload.
For the the first column "primary" I'm using this script below, that works lika a charm.

I know getElementbyID only can get one div, so how could I possibly do?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var strCook = document.cookie;
  if (strCook.indexOf("!~") != 0) {
    var intS = strCook.indexOf("!~");
    var intE = strCook.indexOf("~!");
    var strPos = strCook.substring(intS + 2, intE);
    document.getElementById("primary").scrollTop = strPos;
  }
}

function SetDivPosition() {
  var intY = document.getElementById("primary").scrollTop;
  document.cookie = "yPos=!~" + intY + "~!";
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but wouldn't it be way easier to just use hashtags?

`website.com#primary` > goes to `id="primary`

Comment: Hi Roberrrt! Thanks for your reply, what would that look like in the code, you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you set the cookie seems to be set up primarily for one item - I would change this so that you can set cookies by a key value pairing.

Using some functions for getting and setting cookies, I would then change your code to:

```js
//add cookie functions
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

//I am assuming you will have some sort of on scroll function for setting your cookie.  Change this to a function so you can bind it multiple times
function bindScrollEvent(elementId) {
  var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
  
  element.onscroll = function() {
    setCookie(elementId, element.scrollTop); // use the element id to set the cookie to the scrolltop value
  };
  
  // once the event is bound, you can set it's current scroll position
  var scrollTopPosition = getCookie(elementId);
  
  if (scrollTopPosition !== '') {
    element.scrollTop = scrollTopPosition;
  }
}

// reload the div positions when the document loads
window.onload = function() {
  bindScrollEvent('primary');
  bindScrollEvent('secondary');
  bindScrollEvent('main');
}
```

Comment: First of all, Thank You so much for taking your time to try to help me! Since I'm not so at good at Java Scripts I have to ask you a few questions: Am I supposed to call the script in the HTML id-tag somehow? With onscroll="..."? or similar?  Then I got an error message for the line "if (scrollTopPosition !=== '') {" is there a "=" too much there?. Thanx again!

Comment: hahaha, yeah one extra `=` in there - typo.  you should run this where your other script was running

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help :)  Please could you accept the answer by clicking the tick near the top left of the answer.  Thanks!